# VBA Highlight row if cell value is numeric

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to highlight rows in Excel if they have a numeric values in this column (others are blank), however this code highlights all of them:

```
For lRow = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
    With .Cells(lRow, "AF")
        If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
            .EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274
        End If
    End With
Next lRow
```

Any advice or assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?  You can use `ISNUMBER(...` and the highlighting will be dynamic without re-running the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to check for Numeric values in a cell is also check that the cell is not empty, or contains only spaces, for that you can use `Trim(.Value2) <> ""`.

***Code***

```
If IsNumeric(.Value) And Trim(.Value2) <> "" Then
    .EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274
End If
```

---

**Edit 1**: Faster run-time code.

Using VBA, the tasks which consume the longest are the ones accessing the worksheet, in this case it's `.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274`.

What we can do, is use a `Range` object, in my code it's `ColorRng`, and every time the `If` criteria is met, we add that cell to this `Range`, using the `Union` function. At the end of the code, we just change the color of the `EntireRow` in `ColorRng`, which will result coloring the entire rows which are not numeric at one shot.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorEmptyRows()

Dim ColorRng As Range

For lRow = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
    With .Cells(lRow, "AF")
        If IsNumeric(.Value) And Trim(.Value2) <> "" Then
            If Not ColorRng Is Nothing Then
                Set ColorRng = Application.Union(ColorRng, .Cells(lRow, "AF"))
            Else
                Set ColorRng = .Cells(lRow, "AF")
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next lRow

' if the range has at least 1 cell, color the entire range at the same time
If Not ColorRng Is Nothing Then ColorRng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Empty cells are also considered as numeric with that function. You can use `If Isnumeric(.Value) and .Value <> "" Then` for instance.